# VisualC++ 2010 Debug won't detect code changes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am trying to build a program in VisualC++ 2010 Express, but for some reason the debugger isn't detecting changes.  Working in release does everything correctly.  However, when I'm set in debug mode and I select "debug and build", it will build the file, then run an old executable (it has different output in stdio than what I've written under the changes).  What's most odd is that if I intentionally write in a syntax error, it won't build, but if I write in access of argv way out of range, it will build just fine, but go back to the old exe and run.

Is there a setting or config property that I'm missing?  It only gave me this problem today - before it was working just fine.

Comment: Fixed.  If anyone has the same problem, check the timestamps under your debug files.  Mine were set to an hour later than it was, so technically they were the most "up-to-date," and that's why it wasn't updating them when building the debug executable.

Comment: Is your build failing? There's an option that will make it run an older version if your build fails. I'm not sure where it is, but on a fresh install, it will ask you whether you want it to behave this way or not.

Comment: `argv way out of range` isn't guaranteed to give observable symptoms! It is just undefined behaviour, and the program might run on happily as if nothing happened

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @User1012637. Please put your comment as an *answer*. You're allowed to answer your own questions (perhaps after a waiting period, since you're new here), and later visitors to this site who find this question will appreciate finding the solution in the expected place. In this question's current state, Stack Overflow will present it as a question that has no solution, so future visitors will be less likely to click it and find their answer.

Comment: @RobKennedy I tried to answer it but I've still got a few hours left until it'll let me answer it myself.  Until then I've posted my "answer" as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  There was just an issue of the timestamps under debug files oddly reading 3 hours ahead of the current time, which was keeping the compiler from seeing them as "old"